# How to debug C++ (dap-mode + LLDB or GDB)

Tags: debugging, c++

I want to use `dap-mode` to debug a `C++` code. Until now I followed instructions [dap-mode (LLDB)](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode#lldb) and [lldb-vscode](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/lldb/tree/master/tools/lldb-vscode). I further enabled the mode and UI via

```
(dap-mode 1)
(dap-ui-mode 1)
```

When I execute `dap-debug` I can select the *LLDB template*, but when executing I get the following message:

> **No messages handler for process**

I tried to tweak the template file via `dap-debug-edit-template`. The current template has the following form:

```
(dap-register-debug-template "LLDB::Run"
  (list :type "lldb"
        :cwd "/Users/knowledge/Developer/Tutorials/Cpp"
        :request "launch"
        :program "/Users/knowledge/Developer/Tutorials/Cpp/Debug/main"
        :name "LLDB::Run"))
```

How can I get this running?

Comment: could you be missing lsp-server ?

Comment: Did you try the type as "lldb-vscode"? I saw all [templates](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/lldb/tree/master/tools/lldb-vscode) uses that.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue until I set a breakpoint. After breakpoint debugging is start successfully and execution stops on breakpoint